# Write headers to excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

How do you loop through each element in a list and put it as excel header? Let me know if there is a duplicate question. I couldnt find it so far.

```
row=0
col=0

j = 0
title = ['No.', 'Hue', 'Saturation', 'Value',
         'Lightness', 'AComponent', 'BComponent',
         'Blue Channel', 'Green Channel', 'Red Channel']

for i in title[0:len(title)]:
    worksheet.write(row + 1, col + j, 'title[%i]', bold)
    j += 1
```

I wanted to do something like the text in red
[image]

Comment: Is the black text what you're getting so far? What is `worksheet`?

Comment: @asongtoruin yea the black text is what i am getting so far.... worksheet is from xlsxwriter module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood two things:

1. To iterate over the whole loop, no ranges or indices are needed
2. To substitute some external value into a string, you cannot do what you are doing. Python does not do anything special with the string.

---

You can use `enumerate` for the `j` counter and get rid of a separate counter variable.

```
for j, t in enumerate(title):
    worksheet.write(row + 1, col + j, t, bold)
```

*Disclaimer:* I do not know how to work with `xlsxwriter`, so as far as the question of writing headers is concerned, this may not be the best way. However, what this answer does is address your errors.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks alot, I managed to work it out already with your solution using enumerate. stil got 6minutes before I can accept your ans

Answer (score 5):

You can use Pandas and ExcelWriter module

Create empty DF with columns from your list (i.e. title in your case)

```
import pandas as pd

title = ['No.', 'Hue', 'Saturation', 'Value',
         'Lightness', 'AComponent', 'BComponent',
         'Blue Channel', 'Green Channel', 'Red Channel']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = title) #this create your empty data frame
```

DF TO EXCEL

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

writer = ExcelWriter('YourCSV.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save() #this create Excel file with your desired titles
```

DF TO CSV

```
df.to_csv('YourCSV.csv', sep=',')
```

Comment: its writing the header but its starting from second column ....can you tell why it so?

Comment: Do you mean that you have dataframe and during export to csv it starts from second column?

Comment: Hmm, never happen to me. Is there any chance that on some place in your code you reduce number of columns? Maybe it would help you if you ask another question here :-)

Comment: You must specify the index as illustrated:

`df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1',index=0)`